# UITextField does automatically change its width

Tags: ios, layout, uitextfield

This is my first question here which I could not answer myself with searching on that site.

I have a `UITextField` layout to the left and right of my iPhone app.

When I enter some text into it and the text is more than it can be displayed on that view it does automatically changes it width of that `UITextField` after `textFieldShouldReturn` is called.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Can you describe the layout constraints on the view in question?  I suspect that it's just honoring those constraints...

Comment: Maybe this screenshot describes it better as i would do it ? ;-)
http://s1.directupload.net/images/121207/3tdgrmcq.png

Comment: Ok I have found that problem. 

I didn't know that I could "Pin" (Menu: Editor -> Pin -> Width) and then it works ;)

Comment: You should officially answer your own question.